Save same name attachments in multiple emails
I'm trying to save the attachments in several hundred emails.
I found Saving and renaming an Outlook attachment with static name
The problem is the attachment in every email has the same name and when the macro loops through the attachments it overwrites the previously saved attachment.
Public Sub SaveAttachmentsToDisk(MItem As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim oAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim sSaveFolder As String
    Dim Counter As Integer

    Counter = 1
    sSaveFolder = "C:\Invoices\"
    For Each oAttachment In MItem.Attachments
        oAttachment.SaveAsFile sSaveFolder & "Statments(s)" & Counter & ".pdf"
        Counter = Counter + 1
    Set oAttachment = Nothing
    Next
End Sub

I also tried this macro and got basically the same result.
Outlook Save multiple attachments using the subject line, and incrementing that name

To prevent overwriting the attachments with the same name, your approach of adding a counter to the file name is a good start. However, the issue may arise if the macro processes multiple emails but resets the counter for each one. To ensure unique file names across multiple emails, you can include a timestamp or the subject of the email in the file name for better uniqueness.
Another approach would be to count the number of files in the destination directory and use it as a unique identifier when saving attachments.
You could use something like the code below (untested since I don't use Outlook but the idea should be OK):
Public Sub SaveAttachmentsToDisk(MItem As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim oAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim sSaveFolder As String
    Dim Counter As Integer
    Dim sDate As String
    Dim sSubject As String
    Dim sFileName As String
    
    Counter = 1
    sSaveFolder = "C:\Invoices\"
    
    ' Format the email received date as a string to append to the file name
    sDate = Format(MItem.ReceivedTime, "yyyymmdd_hhmmss")
    ' Clean up the subject to use it in the file name
    sSubject = Replace(MItem.Subject, " ", "_")
    sSubject = Replace(sSubject, ":", "")
    
    For Each oAttachment In MItem.Attachments
        ' Create a unique file name by appending the date and counter
        sFileName = sSaveFolder & "Statement_" & sDate & "_" & Counter & ".pdf"
        
        ' Save the attachment
        oAttachment.SaveAsFile sFileName
        Counter = Counter + 1
    Next
End Sub


Thank you for the reply. I'll give that try.  Using the subject as the file name with a counter makes a lot of sense once you strip out the special characters.
